# How to Send data from Child Component to Parent Component in a ts file?

Tags: angular, typescript

so I have the following, this is the child component, it has a formgroup that has input for check boxes that I want to get count of every time a user clicks the box, for that I have the following

```
@Input() numberTest: number;
@Output() getFinalCheckBox = new EventEmitter<number>();
ngDoCheck(): void{

    this.numberTest = selectedUsers.length;
    this.getFinalCheckBox.emit(this.numberTest);
}
```

now I want to be able to display that number I get from this function numberTest in a .ts file of the parent component, I see more examples of it being displayed in the html so I was confused, the parent component has this:

```
numbertest: any = 0;
steps: any2[] = [{label:"Select Items", nextLabel:`total item selected ${this.numbertest}`, backLabel:"Clear all"},
```

I want to be able to get that selected item total in numbertest from the child component, how can I achieve that?

I am new to angular so I don't know if there are any classes I'll have to extend or anything like that in the parent component

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but if you want to tell the parent component the current value of `this.numberTest` you could use your `@Output() getFinalCheckBox` - `<child (getFinalCheckbox)="methodinParent($event)"></child>`

Comment: basically I want the this.numberTest inside of the ts file of the parent component ,like inside of that any list to have that number, which should come from the child component, what is methodinParent btw?

Comment: you're saying I can add that @Output event in my ts file for my child component or in my parent component? since I Need the this.numberTest value to be in the ts file as its inside of a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In child component it's ok

```
@Output() getFinalCheckBox = new EventEmitter<number>();
ngDoCheck(): void{
    this.numberTest = selectedUsers.length;
    this.getFinalCheckBox.emit(this.numberTest);
}
```

In parent component html :

```
<child-component (getFinalCheckBox)="getNumberTest($event)"></child-component>
```

In parent component ts :

```
public getNumberTest(value) {
 this.numbertest = value
}
```